# How to reset counter column value in Table

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

I want to reset all rows counter column value to zero.

```
UPDATE activities SET meetings = 0 Where tenant = :id
```

It throws following error

> { ResponseError: Cannot set the value of counter column meetings (counters can only be incremented/decremented, not set)

How to reset counter column?

Answer (score 3):

There is no operation that will allow resetting the counter value. You need to read the value and decrement it using that value.

Be aware that this operation might not be successful since the counter can be changed between your "reset" operations.

Comment: For a short moment I hoped that I could wiggle my way around it with something like `SET meetings = meetings - meetings`, but no avail. :(