# How to Reset a Counter Column in Scylla DB to Zero?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, counter, scylla

Is it possible to reset a counter column in `Scylla DB`?

In `Cassandra`, [it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706189) to directly reset a counter column to zero:

> ```
> There is no operation that will allow resetting the counter value. You need to read the value and decrement it using that value.
>
> Be aware that this operation might not be successful since the counter can be changed between your "reset" operations.
> ```

Is this true with `Scylla DB` as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a similar behavior in Scylla.
We cannot reset a counter value to 0, counters can only be incremented or decremented.

```
scylla@cqlsh:ks> CREATE TABLE cf (pk int PRIMARY KEY, my_counter counter);
scylla@cqlsh:ks> UPDATE cf SET my_counter = my_counter + 3 WHERE pk = 0;
scylla@cqlsh:ks> SELECT * FROM cf;

 pk | my_counter
----+------------
  0 |          3

(1 rows)
scylla@cqlsh:ks> UPDATE cf SET my_counter = 0  WHERE pk = 0;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot set the value of counter column my_counter (counters can only be incremented/decremented, not set)"
scylla@cqlsh:ks> UPDATE cf SET my_counter = my_counter - 3 WHERE pk = 0;
scylla@cqlsh:ks> SELECT * FROM cf;

 pk | my_counter
----+------------
  0 |          0

(1 rows)
```

Notice the error when trying to set a value directly.

More about it:

https://docs.scylladb.com/using-scylla/counters/#scylla-counters

https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/types/#counters

https://www.scylladb.com/2017/04/04/counters/